# creating login and welcomenpages using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, authentication

I want to create a login page thats when the user select either remember username or remember me check box, a cookie should be generated, when the remember username checkbox is selected, it should store the username, when the remember me checkbox is selected it should store both the username and password to avoid retyping whena user returns to the login page.

I wrote the preceeding code to incorporate the functionality but on testing the page the user has to retype the username each time the login page is loaded. I am not able to identify the cause of the problem, can someone help me with this?

```
<%
String userName = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String rm_me = request.getParameter("rm_me");
String rm_uname = request.getParameter("rm_uname");

if (userName != null && password != null) {
    if (rm_me != null) {
        Cookie ckU = new Cookie("username", userName);
        Cookie ckP = new Cookie("password", password);
        response.addCookie(ckP);
    } else {
        if (rm_uname != null) {
        Cookie ckU = new Cookie("username", userName);
    }
}

Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if (cookies != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        if (cookies[i].getName().equals("username")) {
            userName = cookies[i].getValue();
        }
        if (cookies[i].getName().equals("password")) {
            password = cookies[i].getValue();
        }
    }
}
%>
```

Comment: Please format your mate! noone can read it like that!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing this kind of stuff in a JSP.  You should use do it in a "controller" servlet and then forward the outcome to a JSP to (just) format the HTML response.

And I think your problem is most likely to be related to that.  Specifically, I suspect that the response will already have been committed by the time that the scriptlet code executes.  This means that your `response.addCookie(...);` call will be too late to add a SetCookie header to the response.

You should be able to confirm this by dumping the response headers when they leave the server or when they reach your browser ... or (less directly) by looking in the browser cookie store.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any introductory book or tutorial on JSP would include examples of everything you want.
Any reasonably recent one will also tell you that using Java code in a JSP is very bad indeed, just don't do it.
Use JSTL instead.